# Can the push-notifications replace web-socket?

Tags: firebase, websocket, push-notification

I need to develop an app on iOS and Android with a realtime function: the app users need to share a code periodically in realtime without polling.

I usually use the web-socket to do it and use the push-notification only for an **additional** notification to user (when app is in background). So, the push-notifications have no impact to application logic (are a plus).

My doubt is, Can I replace totally web-socket communication in favor of the Firebase Push Notification (for receiving) + Rest API (for sending)?
Push Notification are enough reliability?

In general, can push notifications replace websocket for implementing an application logic?

**SOLUTION 1 (WEB-SOCKET + PUSH-NOTIFICATION)**

User A -> App (websocket) -> Server (web socket + push-notification) -> App -> User B

User A <- App <- (web socket + push-notification) Server <- (websocket) App <- User B

**SOLUTION 2 (PUSH-NOTIFICATION + REST API)**

User A -> App (rest-api) -> Server (push-notification) -> App -> User B

User A <- App <- (push-notification) Server <- (rest-api) App <- User B

Comment: I am really interested in the very same concept. Have you tried it? I guess the "only" downfall of push notifs will be the fact, they are not realtime but allow for some lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it is possible. But this choice has a couple of critical flaws:

- First of all, Push Notifications require user permissions, and if the user has blocked Push Notifications, you will be blocked (in your example this means your RestApi will stop working at best) and it is not easy to change this choice for a regular user, the user should go to browser settings ... etc.
- Browser support for [WebPush](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) are much smaller than [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
- There may be a latency between your server and client because the CallStack for such a call is much more than a normal WebSocket connection. Very rough scheme: **YourServer -> PushServer (like Firebase Push Notification) -> Client**
  where at every step there are also many checks.